# Cannot access NancyHost server from another computer/mobile in same network

Tags: webserver, nancy

This is my Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:3000";
            HostConfiguration hostConfigs = new HostConfiguration()
            {
                RewriteLocalhost = true,
                UrlReservations = new UrlReservations() { CreateAutomatically = true }
            };
            NancyHost nancyHost = new NancyHost(new Uri(url), new DefaultNancyBootstrapper(), hostConfigs);
            nancyHost.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Web server running: " + url);

            Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                nancyHost.Stop();
            } catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Web server stopped: " + url);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

After running my program, it ask for administrative permission for adding `http://+:3000/` in `Reserved URL` by executing `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:3000/ user=everyone` this command automatically.

But, after accepting administrative permission, though it adds `http://+:3000/` in `Reserved URL`, but I cannot access my web server from my mobile/another computer which is connected to the same Network with my router.

After too many failures, I also added these `Reserved URL` manually:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:3000/ user=everyone`

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://127.0.0.1:3000/ user=everyone`

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.0.161:3000/ user=everyone` `192.168.0.161 -->` My host computer IP address

But, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake by me.

I just turned off my Public Firewall and it works!!